# Why does my Clojure import fail?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm running Clojure 1.3 with contrib 1.1 in IntelliJ. My program consists of a single line

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.prxml)
```

I get the following error upon running

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.RestFn.<init>(I)V
```

Comment: For Clojure 1.3 projects, `prxml.clj` can simply be copied from contrib [like this](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/extern/cgi-bin/algebra/borch/gitweb.cgi?p=clojure-conexp.git;a=commitdiff;h=80fab31a485855cb6bd04b26a3a559b937b19903).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the answers saying that contrib 1.1 is incompatible with clojure 1.3

Taken from [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib):

> Versions of clojure-contrib are matched to versions of Clojure.
>
> If you are using Clojure 1.0, use clojure-contrib 1.0.
>
> If you are using Clojure 1.1, use clojure-contrib 1.1.
>
> If you are using Clojure 1.2, use clojure-contrib 1.2, or the new [modular Contrib](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib) libraries.
>
> If you are using Clojure 1.3, use the new [modular Contrib](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib) libraries.

As of the date of this reply I'm not sure if there is a version of `clojure.contrib.prxml` that is compatible with `clojure-1.3` (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I would suggest using `clojure-1.2.1` and `clojure-contrib 1.2.0`.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm running Clojure 1.3 with contrib 1.1

There's your problem. Clojure and contrib versions are linked against each other, and are not compatible across versions.

Even more, contrib has been split up into lots of smaller libraries as of 1.3, so there is really no version of "monolithic contrib" that you can use with 1.3.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with the call works with clojure 1.2 and contrib 1.2

If you don't need anything 1.3 specific I would suggest sticking to 1.2 for the time being, use clojure 1.2 and contrib 1.2 until contrib authors properly make the transition to 1.3